# Is there a way to give location to yaml files as locations in @ConfigurationProperties has been removed in version 1.5

Tags: spring-boot

How to use properties defined in various YAML files in a component class.?

Before it used to be done using @ConfigurationProperties(locations="classpath:abc/somelocation.yml") but now  attribute has been removed. What is the other defined way to do this in version 1.5?

I have tried using @PropertySource and defining classpath in that but didn't work for me.
I couldn't understand concept of spring.config.location

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@PropertySource("classpath:applicationConstants.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties("constant")
public class ReadApplicationConstants {

    private String clientId;

    public String getClientId() {
        return clientId;
    }

    public void setClientId(String clientId) {
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }

}
```

And with this I am getting null pointer exception while using getClientId in any method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your clientId comes from the properties file, you have to inject it with the
    @Value annotation on the field. 
Example:

```
    @Value(value = "${clientId}")
```